# Using both "source" and "&" in bash

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I was just reading up on how Unix shells work (`bash` in particular),
and I tried something that didn't make sense to me.

As I understand it, the `source` command runs the program you give it in the current shell process instead of forking a child process.

On the other hand, running a command followed by `&` returns control to the user before the process that runs finishes. If you run a command **without** `source` but **with** `&`, the current shell returns control to the user before the child process exits.

But when I created a file called `test.txt` containing `hello world`, and ran:

```
source /bin/cat test.txt
```

… I got `-bash: ????: command not found`.

Similarly, when I tried to load my virtualenv using

```
source ./venv/bin/activate &
```

I just got the exit status and process id `[1] 26489`

What's going on? Particularly for the second command. I’m confused.

How does `source` work, and what happens when you use it with `&`?

Comment: `source file` or `. file` (for any Bourne compatible shell) will *read* commands from `file` without starting a new process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`source` loads the *bash script file* and interprets it in the current shell environment. `cat` is not a bash script but a binary program file and `bash` cannot successfully interpret its contents as script code. Besides that, bash scripts not designed for use with `source` will possibly misbehave.

> `source filename [arguments]`
>
> Read  and  execute  commands  from `filename` in the current shell
>   environment and return the exit status of the last command  executed from `filename`.  [...] If any arguments are supplied, they become the positional parameters when  filename  is  executed.   Otherwise  the
>   positional  parameters  are unchanged.  The return status is the
>   status of the last command exited within the  script  (0  if  no
>   commands  are  executed),  and false if `filename` is not found or
>   cannot be read.

When you run it with `&`, is will execute in the background. Any change to status will only be displayed when the prompt is printed the next time, and it looks like this:

```
[1]+  Done                    source .bashrc
```

If you really want to launch a program that *replaces* the shell, take a look at `exec`.

```
   exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
          If command is specified, it replaces the shell.  No new  process
          is  created.  The arguments become the arguments to command.  [...]
```

Comment: thanks, that's very helpful. I assume that source run with & doesn't affect the current shell process. (e.g., source ~/.bashrc & doesn't reload your bashrc file)?

Comment: @karansag Apparently, it runs in the same process, but as a background job that does not affect your running session. `cd &` does not change your working directory either.